# Return a constant table from Inline-valued table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Is it possible to return a constant table from an IVT? Now i'm using a regular table, and function is just returning data from this table with several additional operations.

So i want to return a table

```
Value
-----
0,265433
0,0629412
0,671626
```

I tried something like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetEigenvector] 
(   

)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT Value = (SELECT 0,265433 UNION ALL
                    SELECT 0,0629412 UNION ALL
                    SELECT 0,671626)
)
```

but it throws an error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just store the values in table?

Comment: @Stephan because logic should change in the future, it's just a stub, well, not really stub, but just a part of real function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are messing up the syntax for giving an alias to your column:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetEigenvector] 
(   

)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
   SELECT 0.265433 AS Value
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 0.0629412 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 0.671626
)
```

Comment: Also wouldn't you need to use single quotes?   What datatype are you trying to return for Value?

Comment: It doesn't work: CREATE FUNCTION failed because a column name is not specified for column 1.

Comment: @Lamak sorry, could fix it myself. Anyway, thanks, this is what I need

Answer (score 1):

Another syntax:

```
alter function [dbo].[GetEigenvector]()
  returns table as return
  select * from
    ( values (0.265433), (0.0629412), (0.671626) )
    as Eigenvector( Value );
```